# Module Designer issue in Vtiger CRM

Tags: php, vtiger

Please tell me how to create custom module in Vtiger 6 CRM. I have used Module designer module, it works fine for the text box fields, but file upload it is not happening, I need to upload the XLS/CSV file into the Vtiger.

Below code is Manifest.xml created from the Module manager.

```
<field>
<fieldname>image</fieldname>
<uitype>69</uitype>
<columnname>image</columnname>
<columntype>VARCHAR(256)</columntype>
<tablename>vtiger_testingmod</tablename>
<generatedtype>1</generatedtype>
<fieldlabel>LBL_IMAGE</fieldlabel>
<readonly>1</readonly>
<presence>2</presence>
<defaultvalue></defaultvalue>
<sequence>3</sequence>
<maximumlength>100</maximumlength>
<typeofdata>V~O</typeofdata>
<quickcreate>0</quickcreate>
<quickcreatesequence></quickcreatesequence>
<displaytype>1</displaytype>
<info_type>BAS</info_type>
<helpinfo><![CDATA[LBL_IMAGE_INFO]]></helpinfo>
<masseditable>0</masseditable>
</field>
```

**when i use the module i am not receiving any errrors, other details are saving except file upload, Please help me on this.**

**Here is the below link of Module designer, https://github.com/sardoj/VTModuleDesigner**

Comment: Have you looked into why the file upload does not work? What happens when you try - do you get errors? (As it stands there is not much detail here, and probably not enough to attract sensible answers. Please edit the question with more information).

Comment: @halfer it wont throw any errors, just continues the program, in database field will not be saved. i would request you, if you know the UI type of file upload. it will be helpful.